# unable to perform headless PDE build using AJDT in eclipse 3.6

Tags: eclipse, pde, headless, ajdt

i have several simple plugin projects being developed in eclipse 3.6 as part of an rcp application. i also have a very simple aspect. i have read Andrew Eisenberg's article (http://contraptionsforprogramming.blogspot.com/2010/03/ajdt-pde-builds-redux.html) on phasing out ajdt-pde build approach starting in eclipse 3.6, and that allowed me to make the my application work directly in eclipse. however, our official build is headless using Ant, and the following block is how it is compiled:

```
<target name="compile">
    <java classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true" dir="some-dir">
        <arg value="-application" />
        <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner" />
        <arg value="-buildfile" />
        <arg value="${eclipse.location}/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_${some-version}/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml" />
        <arg value="-Dtimestamp=${timestamp}" />
        <arg value="-propertyfile" />
        <arg value="${some-dir}/ant.properties" />
        <classpath>
            <pathelement
                 location="${eclipse.location}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_${some-version}.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

because build.properties is not involved in Ant-based PDE headless build, i am not clear as to where the following entries should be placed:

```
compilerAdapter=org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ant.AJDT_AjcCompilerAdapter
sourceFileExtensions=*.java, *.aj
```

please help me. thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the properties above to the `build.properties` file in every plugin that you are compiling that requires AspectJ.